# Prestashop 1.7 - Send a second email to the customer after registration

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've searched some forums and also here, but I can't find an answer for this question:

Would it be possible to send a second email (based on a custom mail template), to the customer after registration?

I know that are a functions who send the Mail::Send item and I want to send a second email after that action. But I can't find the file with that function. If I found that function I can change the code to send my second mail.

I'm on Prestashop v1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mail is sent by function `sendConfirmationMail()` available in `classes/form/CustomerPersister.php`.

If you want to modify that function, I advice you create an override of this file in `override/classes/form/CustomerPersister.php`

Comment: thansk you!
I have a last question, in what file the function is called?

Comment: In the same file in the functions `create()` and `update()`